# Kubernetes ingress returning a 502 bad gateway

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

So, I am trying to deploy a personal website app and expose it to a local domain (for now) but **I am always getting a 502 Bad Gateway from my nginx-ingress-controller**.
So, for such task I have built 3 files: `deployment.yaml`, `service.yaml` and `ingress.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: website-deployment
  labels:
    app: website
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: website
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: website
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: website
        image: jotinha2014/private
        ports:
        - containerPort: 55004
```

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: website-service
    spec:
      selector:
        app: website
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 80
          targetPort: 55004
      type: ClusterIP
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: website-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rabanadas.eu
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: website-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Here are some logs from my nginx-ingress-controller:

```
2021/01/03 01:13:31 [error] 1371#1371: *34677 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.64.1, server: rabanadas.eu, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.106.8.10:80/", host: "rabanadas.eu"
2021/01/03 01:13:31 [error] 1371#1371: *34677 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.64.1, server: rabanadas.eu, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.106.8.10:80/", host: "rabanadas.eu"
2021/01/03 01:13:31 [error] 1371#1371: *34677 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.64.1, server: rabanadas.eu, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.106.8.10:80/", host: "rabanadas.eu"
192.168.64.1 - - [03/Jan/2021:01:13:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" 474 0.000 [default-website-service-80] [] 10.106.8.10:80, 10.106.8.10:80, 10.106.8.10:80 0, 0, 0 0.000, 0.000, 0.000 502, 502, 502 dff7944bbbc17be35584fee465d047d2
W0103 01:15:52.298006       8 warnings.go:67] networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.19+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
```

Right now I am using minikube and, as such, my nginx-ingress-controller was configure just by adding it as **addon**.
I suspect that the problem is with my ingress configuration because I've already port-forwarded the pod deployed and the website is showing as it is supposed on the right port.

As requested, here are my website pod details:

```
Name:         website-deployment-69f57fc45-l4th9
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/192.168.64.5
Start Time:   Sun, 03 Jan 2021 00:53:16 +0000
Labels:       app=website
              pod-template-hash=69f57fc45
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           172.17.0.2
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.2
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/website-deployment-69f57fc45
Containers:
  website:
    Container ID:   docker://eae48617da80f3ac4832695535432581746d925fc497066a5fd8a707b3020a88
    Image:          jotinha2014/private
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://jotinha2014/private@sha256:0a9573429315745eae0a33339021c82db2e92e0ba35ca652aa20482af31f1219
    Port:           55004/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sun, 03 Jan 2021 00:53:18 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-j8pzx (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-j8pzx:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-j8pzx
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

Thanks in advance fo any help.

Comment: Does you website listen on 0.0.0.0 or localhost only? Please provide more details about what you run inside the container

Comment: Hi João Pacheco, welcome to SO. First off, this question belongs on https://ServerFault.com because it is about networking and not programming. However, in the interest of bringing it back to programming, it is very likely that if the `port-forward` to 55004 works but the Ingress does not, it's probably that your container is listening on 127.0.0.1 and not 0.0.0.0

Comment: @mdaniel Thank you for your reply!
Should I change the nginx-ingress-controller localhost or should the container localhost be changed to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: @x4k3p My website is basically an nginx:alpine with an html template, for now...
So, I would guess that it is listening in localhost!
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: FWIW nginx from dockerhub listens on 0.0.0.0:80 by default, so if you're using that just don't change the defaults ;-) 
It's a bit hard to provide good answers without knowing more about the `jotinha2014/private` image, but 127.0.0.1 cannot be used since it's a loopback address

Comment: @ChristianFosli **jotinha2014/private** is just a `nginx:alpine` with html files on `/usr/share/nginx/html`. I've also tried the same deployment with a wordpress image from dockerhub and I still had the same error (I've choosen wordpress because I was sure the image returned 200 code, to make sure that the problem was not from my app).

Comment: Your Service specifies that you're trying to reach the container on port `55004`. Did you change `nginx:alpine` to use this port, or should the targetPort in your service be `80`?

Comment: The same goes for the containerPort in your Deployment. It needs to match the port that nginx is listening on (which is by default 80)

Comment: @ChristianFosli That actually worked, thank you. So, before changing an image container port, I need to take into account what port does that image listens to by default?
The majority of containers runs on port 80 by default, so I thought that changing it's `containerPort` would be enough.
Could you explain me how could I proceed whenever I want to change a container's default port? Because, in case I have a bunch of apps running, I cannot have them all running on port 80 right?

Once again, thank you for your repply!

Comment: Great :-) I'll rephrase a bit better as an answer. Usually you don't change the port. Usually you run each container in separate pods so it doesn't matter if they're all port 80. How to change port to listen on depends on the application. For nginx you can use a nginx.conf config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments; The `targetPort` in the `Service` manifest, and the `containerPort` in the `Deployment` manifest need to match the port that the server inside the container is listening on.

As nginx by default listens on port 80, these should be changed to port 80.
Otherwise, the server in the container should be changed to listen on a different port. For nginx this can be done with an nginx.conf file, or by setting an `NGINX_PORT` environment variable. See https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx for details.

Usually, you'll run one container per pod, so changing the port to something other than 80 is rarely needed.